# Deleting records using forms in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, form-for, destroy, delete-record

I have two models, users and materials. Users can favourite materials. I have set up the relationships and the code for favouriting works fine but I can't seem to get the code for unfavouriting right. I have the following code for unfavouriting:

**Materials Controller** (in show action where unfavourite form is)

```
@favourite = Favmat.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :material_id => @material.id)
```

Note: I use this code to decide which button to show in the view. Assuming a record exists we get this:

**View**

```
<%= form_for @favourite, :method => :delete do |f| %>
<%= f.submit "Unfavourite" %>
<% end %>
```

The problem seems to be here. Nothing I do seems to get me a working route to the destroy action in the favmats controller. I have tried using a form_tag instead but then I get very odd routes that don't work.

**Favmats Controller**

```
def destroy
  Favmat.find(params[:id]).destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @material }
    format.js
  end
end
```

*Update*

I have also tried using link_to instead of a form. The code is as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Unfavourite", favmat_path, method: "delete" %>
```

The weird thing is that the html for this takes the favmat id from the material, not the favmat object. I don't know how to get the favmat object id in there. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Do you get an error? If I was in your shoes, I would handle "unfavouriting" in `materials_controller`, as an member action.

Comment: I do get an error, yes. I have thought of dealing with the unfavouriting in the materials controller but it's already pretty fat and it seems to make more sense to have actions relating to the Favmats model in the Favmats controller.

Comment: What is an error you get? Could you paste all backtrace? 
Is it maybe `undefined method model_name...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `@favourite` object instead of `favmat_path` to `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to "Unfavourite", @favourite, method: :delete %>
```

Comment: I get: undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class

Comment: @Finnjon try replacing `@favourite = Favmat.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :material_id => @material.id)` with `@favourite = Favmat.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :material_id => @material.id).first`

Comment: Thanks, that works! But why does it need the "first" when there is only one record returned (as each is unique)?

Comment: @Finnjon because `where` always returns a relation, even if it holds only one record. `where` is not that clever to convert a one-record relation to a record so you have to do it manually. Btw, consider marking helpful answer as accepted, please.